# Ways to say “someone who messes with forces they don’t understand”

Tags: nouns, adjectives, personality

I want to describe a character who experiments with sciences they don’t understand, at a great peril they are unaware of.

A hypothetical example of such a person would be a scientist who, in an attempt to study atomic behavior, splits an atom (obvious logistical challenge aside).

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Pandora's Box" metaphors](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188465/pandoras-box-metaphors) where '**let the genie out of the bottle**' is heavily upvoted. '**Playing with fire**' doubtless dates from an age when flame thermodynamics wasn't well understood.

Comment: [Sorcerer's Apprentice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sorcerer%27s_Apprentice)?

Comment: *Tinkerer? Dilettante?* ***Meddler**?* ***Cowboy**?*

Comment: These are good examples of what I am trying to express, but I’m looking for a noun, a title, to describe the person in the story, along the lines of a well-intentioned fool. Maybe a noun meaning “a naive person”. FumbleFingers is on the right track but not quite there...

Comment: A *naïf,* maybe?  Or a *babe in the woods*.